# Error while assigning string literal to array

Tags: c, string, pointers

I define the struct like the following:

```
typedef PACKED struct
{
    UINT8   pedo_config[5]; // 0: male 1: Non 2:weight 3:stepLen 4:height

    INT8 local_name[LOCAL_NAME_LEN_MAX];

}  HOSTINFO;

HOSTINFO hello_sensor_hostinfo;
```

But the warning

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

happened at `hello_sensor_hostinfo.local_name[0]="AAA";`

I also try to change the `INT8 local_name[LOCAL_NAME_LEN_MAX];` to `char local_name[LOCAL_NAME_LEN_MAX];`.

But the warning still alive.

Did I missing something ? Why the warning happened ?

Comment: Did you get a line number with that warning? If so, was it one of these lines?

Comment: Arrays are not *assignable* in C. You need to copy it character by character. Fortunately, there is a function called `strcpy` that does this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not assign *strings* in `C`.

You need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the string lieral into the array.

Also, if you check, the data type for `hello_sensor_hostinfo.local_name[0]` is `INT8` whereas, `"AAA"` represents a `char*` (base address of a *string literal*). Hence the mismatch.

---

FWIW, In your case, `INT8 local_name[LOCAL_NAME_LEN_MAX];` is a compile time array. by using the assignment operator `=`, you're basically trying to change the base address of the array, which is not permitted. You may define `local_name` as a pointer and then you can *assign* the string literal to it. Something like

```
typedef PACKED struct
{
    UINT8   pedo_config[5]; // 0: male 1: Non 2:weight 3:stepLen 4:height

    INT8 * local_name;

}  HOSTINFO;

HOSTINFO hello_sensor_hostinfo;

hello_sensor_hostinfo.local_name="AAA";
```